# How to get instance variables be available in module in World?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have:

```
module A
  H = { c: @user }

  def b
    H.fetch(:c).should_not be_nil
  end
end
World(A)
```

`@user` is defined in Cucumber step. When I invoke it, I get an error as @user is nil.

Note: If I change code to `@user.should_not be_nil`, I won't get an exception.

How to get Cucumber instance variables be available inside modules in World?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a response I got by Matt Wynne in Cucumber mailing list:

> This code doesn't make sense
>
> ```
>    H = { c: @user }
> ```
>
> This line will be run as the module is defined. The @user instance variable you want to use does not exist yet - it will only exist at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
module A
  H = { c: :@user }

  def b
    send(H.fetch(:c)).should_not be_nil
  end
end
World(A)
```